# Ingress does not get address and cannot access from browser

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, minikube

I have a Django application in a container running on port 8000. Its corresponding image is named `test-karpenter-manager:latest` I have put this image into a deployment. When I launch this deployment , I can check the logs and confirm that it starts running sucessfully.

I am generally following this [tutorial](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/ingress-minikube/), which I was able to get working when not deviating from the workflow, but I am unable to get it to work with my own application and I cannot see why.

This is what my .yaml file looks like:

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: my-deployment
  labels:
    app: my-app
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: my-app
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: my-app
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: karpenter-test-manager
        image: test-karpenter-manager:latest
        imagePullPolicy: Never
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8000   # port the pod runs on
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: my-service
spec:
  selector:
    app: my-app
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 8080         # the port the service runs on
      targetPort: 8000   # the port the service points to
---
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: my-ingress
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx-example
  rules:
  - host: hello-world.info
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /api
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: my-service
            port:
              number: 8080     # points to the service port
```

After running this, I can see that the ingress is running, but it gets no address, which the tutorial says should happen:

```
$ kubectl get ingress
NAME         CLASS           HOSTS              ADDRESS   PORTS   AGE
my-ingress   nginx-example   hello-world.info             80      9m28s
```

I have tried connecting to `http://hello-world.info/api` and ``http://hello-world.info:80/api` and neither of them work. I don't know what is wrong or what to do next.

Some notes:

- `/etc/hosts` does contain the relevant line mapping `hello-world.info` to the minikube IP:

```
$ minikube ip
192.168.49.2
$ cat /etc/hosts | grep $(minikube ip)
192.168.49.2    hello-world.info
```

- I am not using rootless docker:

```
$ minikube config view
- driver: docker
- memory: 6000
- rootless: false
- cache: map[localhost/test-karpenter-job:latest:<nil>]
- container-runtime: containerd
- cpus: 4
```

- I have installed the ingress controller and it is running:

```
$ minikube addons enable ingress
  ingress is an addon maintained by Kubernetes. For any concerns contact minikube on GitHub.
You can view the list of minikube maintainers at: https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/blob/master/OWNERS
    ▪ Using image registry.k8s.io/ingress-nginx/kube-webhook-certgen:v20231011-8b53cabe0
    ▪ Using image registry.k8s.io/ingress-nginx/kube-webhook-certgen:v20231011-8b53cabe0
    ▪ Using image registry.k8s.io/ingress-nginx/controller:v1.9.4
  Verifying ingress addon...
  The 'ingress' addon is enabled

$ kubectl get pods -n ingress-nginx
NAME                                        READY   STATUS      RESTARTS   AGE
ingress-nginx-admission-create-pf5bl        0/1     Completed   0          21s
ingress-nginx-admission-patch-q57jm         0/1     Completed   1          21s
ingress-nginx-controller-7c6974c4d8-lmdf7   0/1     Running     0          21s
```

Comment: Have you installed an [Ingress controller](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/ingress-minikube/)?

Comment: Yes, I have installed it, I'll add it to the notes

Comment: The service selector looks wrong. Shouldn't it be `app: my-app`? Not sure if the wrong selector would directly impact the ingress not having an address tbh, but for sure it would make reaching the Pod impossible.

Comment: You are right, but I actually did fix this after I posted, and forgot to update it (I just did). Indeed there is still no address on the ingress.

Comment: `kubectl get ingressclass` -- my guess is that the `ingressclassname` should be `nginx` not `nginx-example`